# Deeplinking - how to?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I'm trying to launch my app from a link in email.

I'm not able to launch my app with a link like this : www.example.com/try/code_like_this_12333dfghjklAsbgfh

but when I try with a code like this : www.example.com/try/

it works.

My manifest is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http"   
    android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/try/.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is the path starting with `/try/`, I recommend using `android:pathPrefix` instead.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data 
    android:scheme="http"   
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/try/" />
```

Comment: The problem is that Gmail doesn&#39;t show me options to open the link and open it directly in Google.